# $[2,5] = \{2,3,4,5\}$ T or F?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand this problem.

Is $[2,5] = \{2,3,4,5\}$ true or false.

What I think: $[2,5] = \{x: 2 \leqslant x \leqslant 5\}$. So this includes 2,3,4, and 5. Therefore it is equivalent so it is true.

Is this right?

Comment: Is $3.1$ in $[2, 5]$?

Comment: Certainly both 2 and 5 are in the interval [2,5] - which I think is the heart of your question.

Comment: Interval = 4 distinct elements?

Comment: What about $\pi$, $\sqrt {5} $, $2.74$  etc. One set is all the real numbers.  The other is all the integers.  They are not the same.  "Includes" means one contains they other but it doesn't mean it *only* contains it.  It contains more.  Example.  {2,3,4,5,6} includes {2,4,6} but obviously the two are not equivalent.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  It's a fair question and the OP expressed and showed thought.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically not true. The notation $[2,5]$ usually denotes the set of all **real** numbers between and including $2$ and $5$. So $[2,5]$ contains infinitely many elements. The set $\{2,3,4,5\}$ on the other hand is finite.

If, though, to you $[2,5]$ denotes the set of **integers** between $2$ and $5$ inclusive, then you are correct.

Comment: The book does not specify real numbers or integers, but seeing as the previous problems all denote the set of real numbers then I will assume it is also for real numbers. So for real numbers [2,5] makes sense that it is not equal to {2,3,4,5}. Thank you for making it clear for me.

Comment: I will state that I have *never* seen [a,b] to refer to only integers.

Comment: @fleablood  I think I've only seen it another time on this site where a cs student asking some discrete math question insisted that [a,b] denotes a list of integers. Some programming languages might suggest this notation: I know in haskell that you can represent {2,3,4,5} as `[2..5]`.

Comment: I have seen situations in which it is declared that we are working solely in $\mathbb Q$ and $[2,5]$ is therefore understood to be $[2,5] \cap \mathbb Q$ so theoretically if it's assumed we're in $\mathbb Z$ then $[2,5]$ *could* be $[2,5]\cap\mathbb Z= \{2,3,4,5\}$ but Ive *never* seen it done, probably do to the discrete nature of integers. [a,b] as a ordered list in programming language has NOTHING to do with ts math notation.  Anyway [2,5] = {2,5} not {2,3,4,5} and [2..5] doesn't look like [2,5]. In programming languages a = a + 5 is a legal thing to say. Programming languages are not math.

Answer (score 2):

Your title does not have the square brackets, so I do not know how to read it.  Then you need to define $[2,5]$.  It is the closed interval from $2$ to $5$, but as a subset of what?  If the naturals or integers, yes.  If the rationals or reals, no.

Comment: It said that I could not use brackets since that is for tags, sorry. I found my mistake using your hint, thank you.